# Что происходит в методе onload класса XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, callback, xmlhttprequest

```js
function easyHTTP() {
  this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

easyHTTP.prototype.get = function(url) {
  this.http.open('GET', url, true);

  let self = this;
  this.http.onload = function() {
    if(self.http.status === 200) {
      return self.http.responseText;
    } 
  };

  this.http.send();
};

const http = new easyHTTP;

console.log(http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'));
```

Почему `return self.http.responseText` возвращает undefined?

Почему если сделать на той же строке так:

- `console.log(self.http.responseText)`

или так:

- `callback(self.http.responseText)`
- `http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(posts) { console.log(posts); });`

то ответ нормально отображается?

Comment: "return self.http.responseText возвращает undefined" - как Вы это выяснили?

Comment: @Igor ещё раз запустите

Comment: Значение, которое возвращается в функции onload, никак никем не используется. В показанном вами коде вы нигде не выводите значение, возвращаемое функцией onload. Если вы видите какой-то undefined, то он абсолютно точно не связан с функцией onload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `get` ничего не возвращает, поэтому - `undefined`.

Comment: Ох, дошло.А как в методе get отловить то, что возвращает onload?

Comment: @Lyy никак, в этом вся суть асинхронной работы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290